# Как в php выделить жирным слова в тексте которые входят в массив без учёта регистра?

Tags: php

например есть текст $text = 'ООО "Строй экспо"' и $reqasts = array('ооо', строй'). Нужно чтобы функция возвращала текст '**ООО** "**Строй** экспо"'. Как это сделать?

Comment: Жирным можно выделить, когда генерируется `html` с этими словами. `<strong>ООО</strong>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```php
$text = 'ООО "Строй экспо"';
$reqasts = array('ооо', 'строй');

$pattern_maker = function($word) { return "#$word#iu"; };
$replacer = function($matches) { return "<b>{$matches[0]}</b>"; };

$patterns = array_map($pattern_maker,  $reqasts);
$result = preg_replace_callback($patterns, $replacer, $text);
```

Результат (HTML!) в переменной $result.

Comment: Огромное спасибо